# Typescript Partial<> typeerror

Tags: typescript

My code has worked already, but now it suddenly has a type error on the logEntry:

```
Type '{ raw: string; timestamp: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<ILogEntry>'.  

    Types of property 'constructor' are incompatible.
    Type 'Function' is missing the following properties from type 'Model<ILogEntry, {}>': base, 
    baseModelName, discriminators, modelName, and 59 more.(2322)
```

What is the correct way to implement this?
This is the example code:

```
import { Schema, model, Model, Document } from "mongoose";
interface ILogEntry extends Document {
raw: string;
timestamp?: number;

}
const logEntry: Partial<ILogEntry> = {
            raw: "hey",
            timestamp: 213213,
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like signature of the `Document` has been changed, if you don't plan to use `constructor` you can simply omit it, if it's acceptable of course.

```js
const logEntry: Partial<Omit<ILogEntry, 'constructor'>> = {
  raw: "hey",
  timestamp: 213213,
};
```

and to avoid length to add a type for it

```js
type PartialObj<T> = Partial<Omit<T, 'constructor'>>;

const logEntry: PartialObj<ILogEntry> = {
  raw: "hey",
  timestamp: 213213,
};
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it does get the error message away, but why do i need to omit the constructor of the document when assigning an object to a variable: ILogEntry?

Comment: I think when `Model<ILogEntry, {}>` is used it requires specific contructor that `ILogEntry` doesn't have and this causes conflict in types, imagine it says constructor with 2 args but it provides constructor with one arg. because we don't plan to specify constructor we need to avoid its type from the partial, then `Model` doesn't see conflict anymore.